# Raster distance for statistical analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, distance, stata

I am trying to some kind of hedonic analysis. I need to calculate driving forces for new urban areas. In order to do this, i have a raster with new urban area's and one with existing urban areas (30x30 meter), 6 different road types, and the population growth in the smallest administrative area. My hypothesis is that existing urban areas and population growth are the most important drivers for new urban areas.

However, to do the analysis in Stata i need the distances from each cell to each other feature (existing urban and roads) and in each cell the population growth corresponding to that administrative area. Then I'll do a regression analysis in Stata in which the dependent variable is urban or not (1 or 0). The distances and population growth per cell are then the independent variables.

My question is, how can i calculate these distances? and have a resulting table with this? I might need to change the resolution, since i have 254 million cells (entire Bangladesh).

I just did the distances using the Generate Near Table-tool, however that gave me distances from the clustered-new-urban-cells-in-polygons to the line-features (roads). And I don't have a dependent variable. So there I made a thinking error.

Comment: So, how would your final attribute table look?  For each row (new urban area), there would be a field entry for the distance to each road, and each existing urban area?  How many road features are there, and how many existing urban areas?

Comment: I think there should be a row for each cell, so that I would have the distance to new urban areas, but also to areas without new urban area. There are 6 different road types, consisting of between 1.000 and 40.000 lines (would dissolving them increase calculation speeds?) And there are 1.5 million cells with new urban area.

Comment: So, your attribute table will have ~254 million rows and a distance calculated field for every road feature?  Or it will calculate to the nearest road for each road type (6)?  And yes, I'm guessing dissolving road features will speed up the process.  Also, if you have the Spatial Analyst extension, you may want to look into the Distance toolset.  It has numerous tools related to calculating distance and cost.

Comment: I overcame the problem by calculating several euclidian distance rasters and using the sample tool with point features generated using the fishnet tool.